# Rails 4 - Sunspot returning empty results on all queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I have a Person model that I wish to perform searches against.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    text :first_name, :last_name, :boost => 2
    text :email, :phone
  end

end
```

I've pulled the search function out of the people_controller because in the long run Im hoping to increase the scope to search all models.  Here is the search controller

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Person.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @results = @people.results
  end
end
```

Im using UJS to render the search results in a search pane on the page.  at the moment search/index.js.erb appends the debug output of the above @results variable.

```
$('#search-results').empty();
$('#search-results').append('<%= j debug @results %>');
```

Every query I attempt returns the following result.

```
--- !ruby/array:Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection
internal: []
ivars:
  :@current_page: 1
  :@per_page: 30
  :@total_count: 0
```

and in the rails console the following is shown.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Sabrina", "commit"=>"Go"}
  SOLR Request (4.7ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Person"], q: "Sabrina", fl: "* score", qf: "first_name_text last_name_text email_text phone_text", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]
```

Its important to note that this query is copy/pasted from one of the people in the database. Initially I was worried that the error tolerance wasn't allowing for even minor misspellings.

This is starting to get pretty frustrating, so far I have deleted and reinstalled the latest JDK, and restarted my machine.  At this point I havn't seen any errors or failed dependancies, etc.  With one possible exception: When I run rake `sunspot:solr:reindex`
I get only the following in the terminal

```
Skipping progress bar: for progress reporting, add gem 'progress_bar' to your Gemfile
```

My question is this: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @people = Sunspot.search(Person) do
  fulltext params[:search]
 end
  @results = @people.results
  end
end
```